# The area bounded by the tangential lines to an even-power exponential function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, area, tangent-line

**The problem:**

Consider a function, $f(x) = x^m$, where $m$ is an even, natural number. Then, consider two tangential lines, grazing the points $(-x,y)$ and $(x,y)$, respectively. My question is, what is the area bounded by those tangential lines and the curve, for any given $m,x$:

[image]

The area in-question has been colored yellow in the picture above. In this example, $m = 2$, $x = 1.5$ and $y = 9$.

**My current research:**

The function for a tangential line is denoted as $t(x)$. The $y$-value of the tangential point between $t(x)$ and $f(x) = x^2$ is denoted as $p_t$.

$$t(x) = -p_t + 2x\sqrt{p_t}$$

$p_t$ is met when $\displaystyle x = \sqrt{p_t}$:

$$-p_t + 2p_t = p_t$$

When I looked at this, I thought I could generalize it to any even $m$. That generalization looks like this:

$$t(x) = -p_t + 2x(\root m\of{p_t})^{m-1}$$

So, when $x = \root m\of{p_t}$, then $t(x) = p_t = x^m$. Problem is, when I tried this with $m = 4$ and $x = 3$, it created a secant line, not a tangent line. Not sure why. It did cross the curve at $(3, 81), 81 = p_t$, but it also crossed it much further below, somewhere in the interval $(7,7.2)$. So, that's where I'm at, trying to figure out a generalized formula for the function of any tangential line to an exponential function of the form $f(x) = x^{2n}$.

And that's simply my current sub-question, within the larger question of *what is this area?*

Comment: Let $t(x)=a+bx$, $f(x)=x^m$. Then at touching point $(x_t,y_t)$: $t(x_t)=a+bx_t=x_t^m=f(x_t)$, $t'(x_t)=b=mx_t^{m-1}=f'(x_t)$. You can express $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x_t$. Then you can find area as $2\int_0^{x_t} (f(x)-t(x))\, dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = x^m ~$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m$ is even.

The curve has symmetry about y-axis so we can find the bound area to the right of y-axis and multiply by $2$.

Slope of the curve is $~y' = mx^{m-1}$

Equation of tangent at point $P ~(p, p^m), ~p \gt 0~$:

$(y - p^m) = m p^{m-1} (x-p)$
$\implies y = mp^{m-1} x - (m-1)p^m$

Height of shell bound between tangent line and the curve is,

$h(x) = x^m - mp^{m-1} x + (m-1)p^m$

So the bound area between the curve and the tangents at points $(p, p^m)$ and $(-p, p^m)$ is given by,

$A = \displaystyle 2 \int_0^p h(x) ~dx = \frac{m (m-1) p^{m+1}}{m+1} $

Comment: Thanks :) As I thought of this problem, I had the feeling that it was a pretty standard calculus problem. Is that the case? If not, is this the first time you've heard of this problem, or have you dealt with it before?

Comment: While I have not dealt with this generic form $y = x^m$, the area bound between $y = x^2$ and tangents at a given $y$ is a pretty common question. This question is very similar except in this case, it is any even $m$ but given the nature of curves $y = x^m$ where $m$ is even, the solution is similar to $y = x^2$ and yes it turns out to be standard calculus work.